# Why is the output order changing when I print using printf?

Tags: c, arrays, char, printf

I want to generate an output like this "firstname surname: day.month.year " but what i get is some mixed up order. I am new to C and I don't know what's going on here.

So this is what i get

[image]

This is my code

```
char string[imax];
fgets (string, imax, team1); //wo, max count, aus welchem file
int i=1, k=0;
char delimiter[] = " ";
char *day, *month, *year, *firstname, *surname;
char *stats[5];

while(fgets(string,imax,team1) != 0)
{
    /*stats[0] = strtok(string,delimiter);
    while(i <=4)
    {
        stats[i] = strtok(NULL,delimiter);
        i++;
    }*/

    day = strtok(string,delimiter);
    month = strtok(NULL,delimiter);
    year = strtok(NULL,delimiter);
    firstname = strtok(NULL,delimiter);
    surname = strtok(NULL,delimiter);

    printf("%s ", firstname);
    printf("%s:", surname);
    printf("%s.", day);
    printf("%s.", month);
    printf("%s. ", year);

}
```

EDIT: I get the same order as the order in the file i am reading from

Comment: Remove the `\n` from the end of `surname`.

Comment: And add a `\n` on the last `printf` statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to add a newline after printing the year. Either change

```
printf("%s. ", year);
```

to

```
printf("%s.\n ", year);
```

or add

```
fputc( '\n', stdout );
```

The second thing is, that after `fgets()` the newline of the source text file is part of `string` and therefore part of `surname`. You can handle this by adding `'\n'` to `delimiter` (and if it's a Windows text file opened on another system (e.g. UNIX), `'\r'` too)

Comment: Don't add `\r` ; when a file is opened in text mode in Windows, `\n\r` is translated to `\n` before your program sees it